# while loops and counters

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've been given this question and I'm trying to not look at the answer before I fully understand why it's not working:

> "Extend your program so that it asks a user for 6 numbers between 1 and 59 inclusive. After 6 numbers have been entered the program should display a message listing the numbers chosen"

```
invalid = True
counter = 0
while invalid and counter <6:
    number = int(input("please enter a number in the range between 1 and 59: "))
    if number >=1 and number <=59:
            invalid = False
    else:
        print("so sorry, your number must be between 1 and 59")
        print("have another go!")

print("well done!")
print (number)
```

---

Does anyone know the simplest way to do this? I've gotten as far as the code above but it doesn't take into account my counter nor do I know how to display the output of the user's input.

Comment: You don't need `invalid`. You just need to increment `counter` when the number *is* valid. And you need to collect the valid numbers in a list so that you can print them all once the loop completes. (Which means you don't need `counter`, either; you can just check the length of your list.)

Answer (score 1):

No need for counter or invalid

```
lst = []                # to contain numbers input by user
while len(lst) < 6:     # know count from length of list
  number = int(input("please enter a number in the range between 1 and 59: "))
  if 1 <= number <= 59: # equivalent, but more readable form than 
                        # if number >=1 and number <=59:
      lst.append(number)   
  else:
    print("so sorry, your number must be between 1 and 59")
    print("have another go!")

print("well done!")
print (lst)             # numbers input by user
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so much! now I know about lists!

Answer (score 0):

```
list = []
counter = 0
failed = False
while counter < 6:
    number = int(input("please enter a number in the range between 1 and 59: "))
    if not 1 <= number <= 59:
        print("so sorry, your number must be between 1 and 59")
        print("have another go!")
        failed = True
        break
    else:
        list.append(number)
        
if not failed:
    print("well done!")
    print (list)
```